# Forwarding Application Logs using nxlog

Tags: nxlog

I want to parse the **Request URL field** in message of application Event Logs by nxlog to kibana but i am not able to parse it as a seperate field.

Please suggest what to do in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the manual: [Example 6.9. Parsing URL request parameters in Apache access logs](https://nxlog.co/docs/en/nxlog-reference-manual.html#xm_kvp_example_apache_url)